# trying to submit form with submit button as button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to submit as form , but it is not working , i want to get the submit button disabled once clicked.

```
<form action="Buy" method="POST" >
  <input type="hidden" name="TID" value="${TID}"/>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">    
  <button onclick="this.disabled = true; document.getElementById('up7913').disabled = false;" type="submit"  name="down7913" id="down7913">Subscribe Now</button></td>
</form>
```

Comment: I see no connection to server side Java in the poorly-formatted HTML snippet you gave above.  Then what is your real problem?

Comment: How you interacting with server ? Its a JSP file or simple HTML code?

Comment: The HTML infers that you have a form as a child of a TR. That's not allowed, so error correction will move it elsewhere. That may have consequences for the form as the input in the TD may not remain in the form. Where is the element with id "up7913"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to the `submit` event and disable the button.

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.down7913.disabled = true;

    // handle POST request
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jefvw66q/1/**